# Histogram not showing data in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I added a prometheus Histogram with name `retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms`. From what I read, three metrics get generated from this. I am able see data when I enter the below in Grafana as is

1. retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_count
2. retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_sum
3. retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_bucket

But when I plot using the below query in Grafana, I don't see any data

`histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(retrieve_stripe_subscription_latency_ms_bucket[5m])) by (le))`

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the the values were all going to the `Inf` bucket since the library I am using doesn't automatically handle that.